# NPM fails with the code: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am fairly new to node and javascript. I am trying to run this on my localhost
https://github.com/bitpay/wallet

originally I was using node.js v14 but I was getting an error. I did some research and found that I should downgrade to node.js v11.

After doing so I get an error after trying to run npm install.

```
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! copay@12.1.1 env:dev: `rm -f src/environments/index.ts && cp src/environments/dev.ts src/environments/index.ts

npm ERR!
npm ERR! # Environment set to: dev
npm ERR!
npm ERR! `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the copay@12.1.1 env:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-01T19_15_48_533Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! copay@12.1.1 postinstall: `npm run env:dev && npm run prompt && npm run patch:bwc && npm run patch:walletconnec
t`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the copay@12.1.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-01T19_15_48_594Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do to fix this. I've read other posts and tried to do what they suggest. I deleted the node_modules file and clear the cache but I am still getting the same error. I've noticed it's saying 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I've tried to change it to del instead of rm but that doesn't seem to help either. Any suggestions on how to get this to work on my localhost?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows. I'm beginning to think that I need a Linux machine for this. I'm going to try and set up a Linux VM. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the first line from the log your shared indicating what is the error

> `'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

it happens since (as you mentioned) you are running windows and i assume you are running npm under cmd or powershell, which does not have `rm` command natively.

i would suggest your to switch to [windows subsystem for linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), which should have system command like `rm` and see whether it solves your issue.